# How to capture screenshot of all 'li' elements one after another with for loop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, screenshot

I have a 10 items in list tag and want to take screenshot of one item of list at a time and so on but the code i have wrote  capturing whole page screenshot and also want to scroll when remaining "li" elements is hidden so then only it should scroll and take screenshot. Below is the code snipped

```
        Image Link -: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB6Nh.png
         
        List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".search-results__list > li"));
        System.out.println("Total number of items :"+list.size());
        //It returns with 10 items
        
        //Scroll and capture screenshot
        for(int i= 1; i<=list.size(); i++)
        {
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".search-results__list > li"));    
            
            //Get entire page screenshot
            File screenshots = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshots);
            
            // Get the location of element on the page
            Point point = Decision_Maker.getLocation();
            
            //Get width and height of the element
            int eleWidth =  Decision_Maker.getSize().getWidth();
            int eleHeight = Decision_Maker.getSize().getHeight();
            
            //Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
            BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(),
                eleWidth, eleHeight);
            
            String location = "E:\\Screenshots\\";              
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            
            //Scroll when element gets hide
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);   
            Thread.sleep(3000);         
            FileUtils.copyFile(screenshots,new File(location +  "img" + i + ".jpg"));
        }
```

Comment: Sure looks like you're overwriting the same filename every time.

Comment: so could please help me how to overcome with this issue??

Comment: what i do is create a method to get the date, and apend date to the file name, so you store screenshots with different names, or also just append the variable (i) so you get name1, name2, name3, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
 FileUtils.copyFile(screenshots,new File(location +  "img" + i + ".jpg"));
```

Comment: Thanks adrian but can you please help me for the some more issues.
I want to take screenshot only 1 "li" element then next but it is taking whole page screenshot and if suppose 2 Li element is visible and remaining are hidden so then only it should scroll otherwise not

Comment: You are saving the element screenshot in this variable "eleScreenshot" so have you tried FileUtils.copyFile(eleScreenshot,new File(location +  "img" + i + ".jpg"));
check out this link
http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/01/how-to-capture-element-screenshot-using.html

Comment: I have written the same code but it is not working for me, if you can tell me something which will work for me??

Comment: please advice me something which can resolve my problem